# Cancan rolify : Defining ability to update resource attribute with block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rolify

I am stuck with this since a bit of time but i don't get the syntax that could make this work.
I want to authorize a User to update an attribute of the instance depending on his role in an association.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't raise an error while trying to update other attributes

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
 ...
end
```

Project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  has_many :stories, dependent: :destroy
 ...
end
```

Story model

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  ...
end
```

Stories controller

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    story = Project.find(params[:project_id]).stories.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, story

    if story.update_attributes(story_params)
      render json: story
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: {errors: story.errors}
    end
  end
 ...
end
```

ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)

    @user = user || User.new
    can :update, Story, :points do |s|
       @user.has_role?(:team_member, s.project)
     end

end
```

Comment: tell in words, please, what you are trying to achieve with this |s|
   @user.has_role?(:team_member, s.project)

Comment: the  |s| @user.has_role?(:team_member, s.project) is to check if the user have the team_member role on the project that got this story... wait i'll update the question with more code of models and controlers

Comment: What version of CanCan are you using? The unreleased 2.x branch?

Comment: Latest one Gemfile.lock says cancancan (1.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

Right now your abilities are tightly coupled to the ability.rb file. Every time you need to add or change a role (or abilities) you have to change your code.

You can add permissions to your roles (as a new another model or just a json field) and iterate over it in the abilities' initializer.

```
  user.roles.each do |role|
    role.permissions.each do |rights, value|
      value.each do |action, subject|
        case rights
        when "can"
          subject == 'all' ? (can action.to_sym, :all) : (can action.to_sym, subject.classify.constantize)
        when "cannot"
          subject == 'all' ? (cannot action.to_sym, :all) : (cannot action.to_sym, subject.classify.constantize)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

So you will be able to store permissions in the DB, edit them with some admin-panel, etc. In your case it might looks like:

```
 # @user.roles.find_by_name('team_member').permissions
 'can' => { 'update' => 'story' }
```